# How do I find the estimated decay constants from my linear mixed effects model?

Tags: r, statistics, linear-regression, lme4, mixed-models

I am trying to figure out how to find the estimated slope for my linear mixed effects model, where I am looking at the decay rate of log-transformed copies of DNA/RNA over time.
My lmer model is as follows:

```r
model1 <- lmer(log.copies ~ 0 + sample + hours + sample:hours + 
                (1 | uniqueID), data)
```

I am trying to find the slope estimate (the decay rate) of each sample, but I am not sure how to find that information. Any insight would be highly appreciated.

Here is the data frame for the model:

```
uniqueID <- c('4a', '4b',   '4c',   '7a',   '7b',   '7c',   '10a',  '10b',  '10c',  '4a',   '4b',   '4c',   '7a',   '7b',   '7c',   '10a',  '10b',  '10c',  '4a',   '4b',   '4c',   '7a',   '7b',   '7c',   '10a',  '10b',  '10c',  '4a',   '4b',   '4c',   '7a',   '7b',   '7c',   '10a',  '10b',  '10c',  '4a',   '4b',   '4c',   '7a',   '7b',   '7c',   '10a',  '10b',  '10c',  '4a',   '4b',   '4c',   '7a',   '7b',   '7c',   '10a',  '10b',  '10c',  '4a',   '4b',   '4c',   '7a',   '7b',   '7c',   '10a',  '10b',  '10c',  '4a',   '4b',   '4c',   '7a',   '7b',   '7c',   '10a',  '10b',  '10c',  '4a',   '4b',   '4c',   '7a',   '7b',   '7c',   '10a',  '10b',  '10c',  '4a',   '4b',   '4c',   '7a',   '7b',   '7c',   '10a',  '10b',  '10c',  '4a',   '4b',   '4c',   '7a',   '7b',   '7c',   '10a',  '10b',  '10c',  '4a',   '4b',   '4c',   '7a',   '7b',   '7c',   '10a',  '10b',  '10c',  '4a',   '4b',   '4c',   '7a',   '7b',   '7c',   '10a',  '10b',  '10c',  '4a',   '4b',   '4c',   '7a',   '7b',   '7c',   '10a',  '10b',  '10c',  '4a',   '4b',   '4c',   '7a',   '7b',   '7c',   '10a',  '10b',  '10c',  '4a',   '4b',   '4c',   '7a',   '7b',   '7c',   '10a',  '10b',  '10c',  '4a',   '4b',   '4c',   '7a',   '7b',   '7c',   '10a',  '10b',  '10c',  '4a',   '4b',   '4c',   '7a',   '7b',   '7c',   '10a',  '10b',  '10c',  '4a',   '4b',   '4c',   '7a',   '7b',   '7c',   '10a',  '10b',  '10c',  '4a',   '4b',   '4c',   '7a',   '7b',   '7c',   '10a',  '10b',  '10c',  '4a',   '4b',   '4c',   '7a',   '7b',   '7c',   '10a',  '10b',  '10c',  '4a',   '4b',   '4c',   '7a',   '7b',   '7c',   '10a',  '10b',  '10c',  '4a',   '4b',   '4c',   '7a',   '7b',   '7c',   '10a',  '10b',  '10c',  '4a',   '4b',   '4c',   '7a',   '7b',   '7c',   '10a',  '10b',  '10c')
hours <- c('0', '0',    '0',    '0',    '0',    '0',    '0',    '0',    '0',    '1',    '1',    '1',    '1',    '1',    '1',    '1',    '1',    '1',    '3',    '3',    '3',    '3',    '3',    '3',    '3',    '3',    '3',    '5',    '5',    '5',    '5',    '5',    '5',    '5',    '5',    '5',    '12',   '12',   '12',   '12',   '12',   '12',   '12',   '12',   '12',   '24',   '24',   '24',   '24',   '24',   '24',   '24',   '24',   '24',   '48',   '48',   '48',   '48',   '48',   '48',   '48',   '48',   '48',   '96',   '96',   '96',   '96',   '96',   '96',   '96',   '96',   '96',   '168',  '168',  '168',  '168',  '168',  '168',  '168',  '168',  '168',  '336',  '336',  '336',  '336',  '336',  '336',  '336',  '336',  '336',  '504',  '504',  '504',  '504',  '504',  '504',  '504',  '504',  '504',  '720',  '720',  '720',  '720',  '720',  '720',  '720',  '720',  '720',  '0',    '0',    '0',    '0',    '0',    '0',    '0',    '0',    '0',    '1',    '1',    '1',    '1',    '1',    '1',    '1',    '1',    '1',    '3',    '3',    '3',    '3',    '3',    '3',    '3',    '3',    '3',    '5',    '5',    '5',    '5',    '5',    '5',    '5',    '5',    '5',    '12',   '12',   '12',   '12',   '12',   '12',   '12',   '12',   '12',   '24',   '24',   '24',   '24',   '24',   '24',   '24',   '24',   '24',   '48',   '48',   '48',   '48',   '48',   '48',   '48',   '48',   '48',   '96',   '96',   '96',   '96',   '96',   '96',   '96',   '96',   '96',   '168',  '168',  '168',  '168',  '168',  '168',  '168',  '168',  '168',  '336',  '336',  '336',  '336',  '336',  '336',  '336',  '336',  '336',  '504',  '504',  '504',  '504',  '504',  '504',  '504',  '504',  '504',  '720',  '720',  '720',  '720',  '720',  '720',  '720',  '720',  '720',)
log.copies <- c('1.45521893628741', '1.45521893628741', '1.45521893628741', '1.45521893628741', '1.45521893628741', '1.45521893628741', '1.45521893628741', '1.45521893628741', '1.45521893628741', '1.19441603388691', '1.24355334723342', '1.40690849045049', '1.31002191752687', '1.39124834261194', '1.29235753729037', '1.11936230018844', '1.1374556403934',  '1.39758382302761', '1.68018850963636', '1.25191207562977', '1.23641746512146', '1.39679718172058', '1.38090501093842', '1.24605609103987', '1.21030026698775', '1.19544292124108', '1.17601950399624', '1.31273309142159', '1.26185528648986', '1.25966627646237', '1.31215362175609', '1.1797649397335',  '1.06962991082736', '1.06648871526762', '1.01999877463483', '1.0713647526277',  '1.33727512803554', '1.32714821681501', '1.36095600888816', '1.20806814685821', '1.01506836010089', '1.16512723872603', '1.26641479125218', '1.09785021474546', '1.13833983315088', '1.23033598728608', '1.40813602545636', '1.4646125625919',  '1.00258079576351', '1.17601950399624', '1.06788775208508', '1.04454452321033', '1.05059619746453', '1.03045177956328', '1.37430638458471', '1.41452140821272', '1.75913091767113', '0.77346280655772', '0.767002923329097',    '1.01188172732087', '0.74623404934399', '0.944256557003784',    '1.05150543231433', '1.2251192503473',  '1.29174874539612', '1.43997134954361', '-0.0296134397450946',  '-0.286448979024821',   '-0.156823792139869',   '0.839166900510674',    '0.724365376990744',    '0.678610613822442',    '0.786777342262311',    '1.29478377172835', '1.37297391495997', '-0.82434417051388',    '-0.82434417051388',    '-0.496558364627612',   '0.0829498390130417',   '0.427489632415672',    '0.158891649802325',    '1.49438314328631', '0.729149969776687',    '0.819893243439029',    '-0.82434417051388',    '-1.1900799975662', '-1.1900799975662', '-0.717704531413791',   '-0.398265926539503',   '-0.362000706739917',   '-0.196897956423786',   '0.64307632093276', '0.675913769256037',    '-0.717704531413791',   '-1.1900799975662', '-1.1900799975662', '0.0555326061931463',   '-0.822304338094534',   '-0.507174381784299',   '0.180394322691316',    '0.640136342503974',    '0.393190666987189',    '-1.1900799975662', '-0.967508136400586',   '-0.967508136400586',   '-0.823663106508838',   '-0.967990407588446',   '-0.967026427628234',   '0.171315600631744',    '0.171315600631744',    '0.171315600631744',    '0.171315600631744',    '0.171315600631744',    '0.171315600631744',    '0.171315600631744',    '0.171315600631744',    '0.171315600631744',    '-0.386292183084873',   '-0.0999771866567739',  '0.0867221503952878',   '-0.525277163372224',   '0.00383206432719449',  '-0.0999771866567739',  '-0.199592846032811',   '0.047352829483974',    '0.408978520878843',    '-0.386292183084873',   '-0.617450004710004',   '-0.525277163372224',   '-0.0714786306395753',  '-0.163651471977355',   '0.171315600631744',    '0.067506349647776',    '-0.0448200118538059',  '0.047352829483974',    '-0.617450004710004',   '-0.617450004710004',   '-0.525277163372224',   '-0.331135008281905',   '0.0261653532722218',   '-0.0197780887736235',  '-0.0448200118538059',  '-0.163651471977355',   '-0.0197780887736235',  '-0.282482932100905',   '-0.163651471977355',   '-0.903765001138104',   '-0.331135008281905',   '-0.199592846032811',   '-0.238962166944125',   '-0.525277163372224',   '-0.386292183084873',   '-0.386292183084873',   '-1.1900799975662', '-0.903765001138104',   '-0.903765001138104',   '-1.1900799975662', '-1.1900799975662', '-0.903765001138104',   '-0.903765001138104',   '-0.903765001138104',   '-1.1900799975662', '-1.1900799975662', '-0.903765001138104',   '-1.1900799975662', '-1.1900799975662', '-0.903765001138104',   '-0.903765001138104',   '-1.1900799975662', '-1.1900799975662', '-1.1900799975662', '-0.903765001138104',   '-0.903765001138104',   '-1.1900799975662', '-1.1900799975662', '-1.1900799975662', '-0.903765001138104',   '-1.1900799975662', '-1.1900799975662', '-1.1900799975662', '-1.1900799975662', '-1.1900799975662', '-1.1900799975662', '-1.1900799975662', '-1.1900799975662', '-1.1900799975662', '-1.1900799975662', '-1.1900799975662', '-0.903765001138104',   '-1.1900799975662', '-1.1900799975662', '-1.1900799975662', '-1.1900799975662', '-1.1900799975662', '-1.1900799975662', '-1.1900799975662', '-1.1900799975662', '-1.1900799975662', '-1.1900799975662', '-1.1900799975662', '-0.903765001138104',   '-1.1900799975662', '-1.1900799975662', '-1.1900799975662', '-0.903765001138104',   '-0.903765001138104',   '-0.903765001138104',   '-1.1900799975662', '-0.903765001138104',   '-1.1900799975662', '-1.1900799975662', '-1.1900799975662', '-1.1900799975662', '-1.1900799975662', '-0.903765001138104',   '-1.1900799975662')
sample <- c('4eDNA',    '4eDNA',    '4eDNA',    '7eDNA',    '7eDNA',    '7eDNA',    '10eDNA',   '10eDNA',   '10eDNA',   '4eDNA',    '4eDNA',    '4eDNA',    '7eDNA',    '7eDNA',    '7eDNA',    '10eDNA',   '10eDNA',   '10eDNA',   '4eDNA',    '4eDNA',    '4eDNA',    '7eDNA',    '7eDNA',    '7eDNA',    '10eDNA',   '10eDNA',   '10eDNA',   '4eDNA',    '4eDNA',    '4eDNA',    '7eDNA',    '7eDNA',    '7eDNA',    '10eDNA',   '10eDNA',   '10eDNA',   '4eDNA',    '4eDNA',    '4eDNA',    '7eDNA',    '7eDNA',    '7eDNA',    '10eDNA',   '10eDNA',   '10eDNA',   '4eDNA',    '4eDNA',    '4eDNA',    '7eDNA',    '7eDNA',    '7eDNA',    '10eDNA',   '10eDNA',   '10eDNA',   '4eDNA',    '4eDNA',    '4eDNA',    '7eDNA',    '7eDNA',    '7eDNA',    '10eDNA',   '10eDNA',   '10eDNA',   '4eDNA',    '4eDNA',    '4eDNA',    '7eDNA',    '7eDNA',    '7eDNA',    '10eDNA',   '10eDNA',   '10eDNA',   '4eDNA',    '4eDNA',    '4eDNA',    '7eDNA',    '7eDNA',    '7eDNA',    '10eDNA',   '10eDNA',   '10eDNA',   '4eDNA',    '4eDNA',    '4eDNA',    '7eDNA',    '7eDNA',    '7eDNA',    '10eDNA',   '10eDNA',   '10eDNA',   '4eDNA',    '4eDNA',    '4eDNA',    '7eDNA',    '7eDNA',    '7eDNA',    '10eDNA',   '10eDNA',   '10eDNA',   '4eDNA',    '4eDNA',    '4eDNA',    '7eDNA',    '7eDNA',    '7eDNA',    '10eDNA',   '10eDNA',   '10eDNA',   '4eRNA',    '4eRNA',    '4eRNA',    '7eRNA',    '7eRNA',    '7eRNA',    '10eRNA',   '10eRNA',   '10eRNA',   '4eRNA',    '4eRNA',    '4eRNA',    '7eRNA',    '7eRNA',    '7eRNA',    '10eRNA',   '10eRNA',   '10eRNA',   '4eRNA',    '4eRNA',    '4eRNA',    '7eRNA',    '7eRNA',    '7eRNA',    '10eRNA',   '10eRNA',   '10eRNA',   '4eRNA',    '4eRNA',    '4eRNA',    '7eRNA',    '7eRNA',    '7eRNA',    '10eRNA',   '10eRNA',   '10eRNA',   '4eRNA',    '4eRNA',    '4eRNA',    '7eRNA',    '7eRNA',    '7eRNA',    '10eRNA',   '10eRNA',   '10eRNA',   '4eRNA',    '4eRNA',    '4eRNA',    '7eRNA',    '7eRNA',    '7eRNA',    '10eRNA',   '10eRNA',   '10eRNA',   '4eRNA',    '4eRNA',    '4eRNA',    '7eRNA',    '7eRNA',    '7eRNA',    '10eRNA',   '10eRNA',   '10eRNA',   '4eRNA',    '4eRNA',    '4eRNA',    '7eRNA',    '7eRNA',    '7eRNA',    '10eRNA',   '10eRNA',   '10eRNA',   '4eRNA',    '4eRNA',    '4eRNA',    '7eRNA',    '7eRNA',    '7eRNA',    '10eRNA',   '10eRNA',   '10eRNA',   '4eRNA',    '4eRNA',    '4eRNA',    '7eRNA',    '7eRNA',    '7eRNA',    '10eRNA',   '10eRNA',   '10eRNA',   '4eRNA',    '4eRNA',    '4eRNA',    '7eRNA',    '7eRNA',    '7eRNA',    '10eRNA',   '10eRNA',   '10eRNA',   '4eRNA',    '4eRNA',    '4eRNA',    '7eRNA',    '7eRNA',    '7eRNA',    '10eRNA',   '10eRNA',   '10eRNA')
```

What I'd like to find now is the slope of each of the "samples", e.g. the slope of the log.copies of 4eRNA against hours, etc.

Here's an example of what I'm looking for (these are just dummy values)

[image: 1]

Comment: See here: <https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/122009/extracting-slopes-for-cases-from-a-mixed-effects-model-lme4>

Comment: I have tried to go through that example using coef previously, but keep getting a NULL output in return. I am not sure what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Hello, welcome to SO! We will do our best to help but won't be able to do much if we can't recreate the problem. Look at this link to see tips on creating a minimal working example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Hello, I have just added an example of the data frame used. Please let me know if I can provide any additional information. Thank you!

Comment: (1) Is there a reason the hours and log.copies values (which should presumably be numeric) are given here as character vectors ... ?? (2) do you want the uniqueID-specific slopes or the population level slopes (for the latter you want `fixef`, not `coef` ...)

Comment: Hi Ben, sorry about that; 1) yes, those should be numeric vectors. 2) I am looking for  the estimated slope for each sample only i.e. for 4eDNA, 4eRNA, 7eDNA...etc. and not for the uniqueIDs.

Comment: To clarify: For example, the output table I'm looking for is supposed to have the headings "sample", "Estimate", "SE," "df", "lower.CL" and "upper.CL". How would I go about getting that for just my samples? Thanks in advance for your time and help, it is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After cleaning up the data a bit (converting to numeric):

```r
d <- data.frame(log.copies, sample, hours, uniqueID)
library(lme4)
## use `0 + sample + sample:hours` to fit intercept & slope
##  separately for each sample
model1 <- lmer(log.copies ~ 0 + sample + sample:hours + (1 | uniqueID), d)
## fixed-effect coefficient table
cc <- coef(summary(model1))
cc[grepl("hours", rownames(cc)),]
```

Results:

```r
                       Estimate   Std. Error    t value
sample10eDNA:hours -0.003205399 0.0003059636 -10.476405
sample10eRNA:hours -0.001238915 0.0003059636  -4.049224
sample4eDNA:hours  -0.001525579 0.0003059636  -4.986143
sample4eRNA:hours  -0.001060511 0.0003059636  -3.466135
sample7eDNA:hours  -0.003824935 0.0003059636 -12.501274
sample7eRNA:hours  -0.001456568 0.0003059636  -4.760591
```

If you load `lmerTest` after or instead of `lme4` your table will include `df` and `Pr(>|t|)` columns as in your example.

To get the *specific* table you're looking for, I think you want

```r
emmeans::emtrends(model1, ~sample, var="hours")
 sample hours.trend       SE  df lower.CL  upper.CL
 10eDNA    -0.00321 0.000306 198 -0.00381 -0.002602
 10eRNA    -0.00124 0.000306 198 -0.00184 -0.000636
 4eDNA     -0.00153 0.000306 198 -0.00213 -0.000922
 4eRNA     -0.00106 0.000306 198 -0.00166 -0.000457
 7eDNA     -0.00382 0.000306 198 -0.00443 -0.003222
 7eRNA     -0.00146 0.000306 198 -0.00206 -0.000853
```

Note that the estimates are the same up to rounding as the previous table, although `emmeans` is more convenient because it computes CI for you and you can specify the model any way you want, e.g. as `~ sample*hours + (1|uniqueID)`, and still extract the same table.

Comment: Thank you Ben; however I'm looking for just the sample slopes. I posted an image in the question for an example. Is it possible to get something like that?

Comment: I think that's exactly what I'm showing you ... .?

Comment: Ahhh I see what you mean. This makes sense, thank you!!

Comment: If this solved your problem you're encouraged to click the check-mark to accept it.